# Use of undeclared identifier 'VZMacKeyboardConfiguration'

Tags: xcode, virtual-machine, apple-m1

I am attempting to follow the guide, [Running macOS in a virtual machine on Apple silicon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/running_macos_in_a_virtual_machine_on_apple_silicon).

I downloaded the file `RunningMacOSInAVirtualMachineOnAppleSilicon.zip`, extracted it, and opened the project in Xcode. I used my personal Apple developer profile for signing.

Now, I'm seeing an error.

```
MacOSVirtualMachineConfigurationHelper.m:84:18 
Use of undeclared identifier 'VZMacKeyboardConfiguration'
```

This is the code it's trying to build:

```
+ (VZKeyboardConfiguration *)createKeyboardConfiguration
{
    if (@available(macOS 14.0, *)) {
        return [[VZMacKeyboardConfiguration alloc] init];
    } else {
        return [[VZUSBKeyboardConfiguration alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Update: I'm actually running macOS 13 and Xcode 14, and after re-reviewing the docs, it seems that this requires macOS 14 and Xcode 15.

Is there a way to build on macOS 13 with Xcode 14?

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, the solution is to upgrade to macOS 14 and Xcode 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing "for real," it's probably a good idea to upgrade to MacOS 14. But if you just want to run the sample (like I did), it may be better to remove the branches that use it. I ran the [same sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/running_macos_in_a_virtual_machine_on_apple_silicon) and needed to update code in 2 places (just follow the error messages), along with changing the MacOS deployment target to 13.0.